# Elasticsearch - Http\Discovery\Strategy\GeneratedDiscoveryStrategy.php Failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I'm using PHP 8 and Elasticsearch 8 through Composer. I thought it was very easy to use this feature but somehow I got the error: Http\Discovery\Strategy\GeneratedDiscoveryStrategy.php Failed to open stream: No such file or directory
[Stack trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jnym.png)

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Elastic\Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder;

$client = ClientBuilder::create()->build();
```

Comment: May i know how did you install ES php sdk? As i test it worked on my machine.

Comment: Thank you @AshishTiwari, the problem was resolved since the existing code of the project has required a class that never existed and didn't validate it